# Getting property from c# anonymous object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, recursion, anonymous-types

On a server, I get JSON objects. I use JsonConvert to deserialize them into anonymous objects. I then want to access the members, but I can't do something like:

```
object a = jsonObj.something.something.else;
```

So I created the following, with the intention of being able to access a member using an array of selector strings. However, getProperty() here always returns null. Any ideas?

```
private object recGetProperty(object currentNode, string[] selectors, int index) {
    try {
        Type nodeType = currentNode.GetType();
        object nextNode = nodeType.GetProperty(selectors[index]);
        if (index == (selectors.Length - 1)) {
            return nextNode;
        }
        else {
            return recGetProperty(nextNode, selectors, index + 1);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }           
}

private object getProperty(object root, string[] selectors) {
    return recGetProperty(root, selectors, 0);
}
```

Comment: `but you can't do something like:...` Why? have you tried to use *dynamic* keyword?

Comment: you can with dynamics.  Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: I'm new to c#. I haven't heard of this yet. I'll look into it.

Comment: dynamic allows for the "." notation access, but can this be used to access using a series of strings? String indexing doesn't work on a dynamic type object, it seems.

Answer (score 7):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` does not deserialize to anonymous object (I guess, you don't use *JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType*). Depending on json it returns either `JObject` or `JArray`.

**1.** Since *JObject* implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>` you can use it this way

```
string json = @"{prop1:{prop2:""abc""}}";

JObject jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
Console.WriteLine(jsonObj["prop1"]["prop2"]);
```

or

```
string str = (string)jsonObj.SelectToken("prop1.prop2");
```

**2.** If you want to use the *dynamic* keyword, then

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.prop1.prop2);
```

Both ways will print `abc`

Answer (score 0):

my code

```
Dictionary<string, object> dictionaryObject = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (anonymousObject is string)
        {
            dictionaryObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,object>>((string)anonymousObject);
        }
        if (!dictionaryObject.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            throw new Exception($"property name '{propertyName}' not found");
        }
        object value = dictionaryObject[propertyName];
```